# Keep getting NaN after adding numbers - jQuery

Tags: jquery, nan

I have this script:

```
var foo=0;

$('#container .field').each(function(){
     var item = $(this);
     foo += parseInt(item.val());
})

console.log(foo);
```

But each time, when I log the tot-variable, it shows NaN. The .field class is given to input fields.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would first say that item.val() is not a number.  before saying that, instead of using parseInt()  use Number(item.val());
if that does not work, your value is not a number

Answer (score 6):

This can happen if you've got a value in one of your fields that can't be parsed as an integer.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sFL9g/1/) for a solution:

```
// Note: add 10 as the radix parameter to indicate you want
// base-10 integers.
foo += parseInt(item.val(), 10) || 0;
```

This will effectively skip over values that can't be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but I also couldn't set foo to 0 very easily beforehand as it was being created dynamically, I got around it by using Dan's solution but also put the or on the foo too:

```
foo = (foo || 0) + (parseInt(item.val()) || 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript console:

- NaN || 0 --> 0
- undefined || 0 --> 0

So in case a number you want to add you could do something like:

```
var foo=2;
foo+=NaN || 0 + 2;
```

or in your case:

```
foo += parseInt(item.val()) || 0 ;
```